# why diagonals in a pair plot is a histogram instead of line plot?

Tags: machine-learning, linear

why do diagonals in a pair plot is a histogram instead of a line plot? Doesn't it make sense to have a line plot with the 45-degree linear line passing through the origin? This is a general question that applies to any pairplot. In case, I'm just attaching a pairplot image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the pair plot in the diagonal would be points on the diagonal. Since everybody knows this, there is not much of a point in showing this. But what points on the diagonal would not show very well is how those points are distributed along the diagonal, at which locations there is high and at which there is low density. So, instead of giving information that is known anyway, you are given information that is of additional value.

Comment: You may be right. Because, only distribution kind of plots such as hist/dist/kde, etc are the only one that seems to work along the diagonals.